# Repl.it Python 3 Short cut Comment/Uncomment a block

Tags: python, python-3.x

I searched for a shortcut command that would comment/uncomment a block for repl.it.
I'm working on a python 3 project and I often need to comment a big section of my code.

Is there a shortcut command for that?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

[It's on their help page](https://repl.it/help)

Like most code editors.

> Ctrl-/    | Command-/ | Toggle comment

Answer (score 2):

To comment a block of Python code on Repl on a windows machine:

1. Select block of lines to comment
2. Type "Ctrl + K" followed by "Ctrl + C"

To uncomment use: "Ctrl + K" followed by "Ctrl + U"

Answer (score 1):

From the command palette: ( <kbd>Ctrl</kbd> + <kbd>Shift</kbd> + <kbd>P</kbd> )

- Add line comment: <kbd>Ctrl</kbd> + <kbd>K</kbd> / <kbd>Ctrl</kbd> +<kbd>C</kbd>
- Remove line comment: <kbd>Ctrl</kbd> + <kbd>K</kbd> / <kbd>Ctrl</kbd> + <kbd>U</kbd>